# Git で Unity を使ったソースコードを版管理をするには？

Tags: git, unity3d

Web系などでよく使われるGitでUnityのソースコードを管理するときに気をつける点はなんでしょうか。

※英語版で最も人気のあるUnityの質問を投稿してみます。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

適切な.gitignoreを追加してプロジェクトに必要のない一時ファイルを無視すること。
以下のURLのものをとりあえず入れておけばいいと思います。
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore

それと、git addする際にmetaファイルを忘れずに追加すること。

この二点が最低必要だと思います。

Answer (score 4):

meta file を force text にすることも推奨です。テキストなので、差分がある程度わかります。

Comment: 設定関係でいうと英語には下記の言及がありました。

Switch to Visible Meta Files in Edit → Project Settings → Editor → Version Control Mode.
Switch to Force Text in Edit → Project Settings → Editor → Asset Serialization Mode.
Save the scene and project from File menu.

Comment: Metaの設定についてTakashikiさんの回答に追記してまとめようかなと思っています。

Answer (score 2):

SceneファイルなどのバイナリがConflictした時の対処がとても面倒だったので、複数人で同時にSceneファイルは編集しないようなルールは有った方がいいと思います。（当時自分が所属していたチームではそうしていました）

Answer (score 2):

Unity で生成されるファイルはデフォルトでバイナリになっていて,
競合が起きると困るので最初にテキストモードに切り替えておくことをオススメします.

先ほどちょうどそのことについて書いたのでよかったら参考までに
http://qiita.com/phi/items/95c21957fbe771f5a9a8

とはいえ, Scene などは複数人で編集した場合は競合が起きるので,
同じシーンを同時に編集するってことはあまりやらないようにしてましたね.

Answer (score 2):

有償のプラグインを使用する際には、プラグイン絡みの部分はライセンスを保持している人だけがアクセスできるようにする必要があります。
ですので、プラグイン周りはリポジトリを分離するといいかもしれません。